# Sorting Custom Post Type by Meta Value but wont display when set to 0

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I'm trying to sort by custom meta data for posts. The custom meta is forum_order. The posts currently only display when the value is either minus or above 0. I would like the default to be 0 so unless the user sets it it will be displayed alphabetical.

```
$forum_category_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'forums', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key'  => 'forum_order', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'meta_query'  => array( 
            array( 
                'key' => 'forum_type', 
                'value' => 'category'
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
);

while ( $forum_category_query->have_posts() ) : $forum_category_query->the_post();
```

I have spent hours searching on Google and on here but I'm so confused!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

I had this in the function to save the meta data (like an idiot!!)

```
if ( !$value ) delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key ); // Delete if blank
```

So it wasn't saving the meta value if set to 0.

I changed it to:

```
if ( !$value ) add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, '0' ); // add 0 if blank
```

Simple to solve... after hours of agony.

Answer (score 0):

try this to do a double sort.
on `forum_order` first and by `title` if `forum_order` values are the same

```
$forum_category_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'forums',
        'meta_key'  => 'forum_order', 
        "orderby" => [
            "meta_value_num" => "ASC",
            "title" => "ASC",
        ],
        'meta_query'  => array( 
            array( 
                'key' => 'forum_type', 
                'value' => 'category'
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the post still disappear when forum_order is 0!